# How to use several conditions with QUERY + IMPORTRANGE in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get unique values by using this formula:

`=UNIQUE(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/here goes link","Income!2:8000"),"Select Col15,Col16, Col26 where Col3=" & "'" & B2 & "'"))`

And I'm getting the result that I need. The only problem is that I'd like to add an additional condition to it and have no idea how to do it.

I'd like this formula to filter values not only based on Col3 but based on another one, for example, `Col3 = B2` and `Col2 = A2`.

Does anyone have any idea how to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Update: based on the sheet and the data format you have shared, this formula should work:

`=UNIQUE(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pXFIWzeHcJPQJtjUqOdgi2FusNGEUoeGlA5rLGNuKLQ/edit#gid=0","data!2:500"),"Select Col15, Col16, Col26 where Col3 = '"&B2&"' and Col2 = date'"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(A2), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")`

You can use `and` with `where` to check for multiple conditions.

`=UNIQUE(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/here goes link","Income!2:8000"),"Select Col15, Col16, Col26 where Col3 = '"&B2&"' and Col2 = '"&A2&"'"))`

Comment: I've tried this earlier and I'm getting formula parse error.

Comment: Can you share a sheet with some sample data and the desired output in it? Would be easier to troubleshoot that way

Comment: Hi Broly, please see the sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pXFIWzeHcJPQJtjUqOdgi2FusNGEUoeGlA5rLGNuKLQ/edit#gid=1480583499. You may find this formula on Sheet 2 in the Col 3.

Comment: Can you use the formula I've shared above? I don't see the
and Col2 = '"&A2&"'"
part in your formula. Since the current formula in the sheet is returning multiple rows and you have the formula added on every row, the results have no place to expand and hence the error.

Comment: Sure, I've updated the table below with your part and I'm getting "Query completed with an empty output" error https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pXFIWzeHcJPQJtjUqOdgi2FusNGEUoeGlA5rLGNuKLQ/edit#gid=1480583499

Comment: Filtering by date works a little differently when using QUERY so I have updated the original answer to reflect that.